# How to retrieve object with relationship stored in string variable in rails 3.2.12 at run time?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say there are models `customer`, `account` and `address`:

```
class Customer
  has_many :accounts
end

class Account 
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :addresses
end

class Address
  belongs_to :account
end
```

Given an object address, its customer could be retrieved as:

```
customer = address.account.customer
```

Now let's store the relationship in a string variable `address_relation = 'account.customer'`. Given an `address` object, is there a way to retrieve its `customer` with the string variable `address_relation` like:

`customer = address.address_relation` ?

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like

```
customer = address.address_relation.split(".").inject(address) do |object, method| 
  object.send(method)
end
```

You could switch `send` by `try` if there's a chance there is a nil object in your relation chain

Comment: yep, this is a actually a much better example than mine. I was editing  my snippet to turn it into a recursive function, but using inject/reduce is actually much more coincise.

Comment: @user938363 `inject` is in the standard ruby library. Let's assume you have a collection of a1, a2, a3, ... objects. Using `inject` with a block named `f` is equivalent to calling `f(f(f(base, a1), a2), a3)...`. For each member of the collection, the block is called and given as params 1/ the return value of the previous call 2/ the current item itered upon. `base` is used for the first call, when there is not yet a previous return value.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the problem correctly, but I guess you can use Ruby's [send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send) method to dynamically resolve the model relations.

```
object  = customer
methods = "account.customer".split(".")

methods.each do |m|
  object = object.send(m)
end
```